# regex time over multiline

Tags: php, regex

Why does this regex not work over linebreak?

```
preg_match("/((?:(?:(?:[0][1-9]|1[0-2]|[0-9]):[0-5][0-9])\s(?:AM|PM)))/msiU", $input, $output_array);
```

does not match

```
text 13:30
PM moretext
```

see: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/joB

Comment: Try it with `\s+` or `\s*` as your line break may be made up of multiple characters.

Comment: The `am`/`pm` can be simplified to `[AP]M`.

Comment: ha, how is that simpler?

Comment: @Scuzzy Eliminates non-capture group and alteration

Comment: also, the `m` and `s` flags are not needed here. The `m` flag is only useful if you are using the `^` and `$` anchors. And the `s` flag is only used if you are using a `.*`.

Comment: @chris85 Good call, I revoke my "ha"

Comment: If we are to talk about what is redundant in the pattern, it is definitely the outer capturing group and the `U` modifier. The only relevant modifier is `/i`, the rest can be removed. The first two non-capturing groups also seem redundant.

Comment: To finish use an other regex tester (regex101.com) since each line in phpliveregex is a separated string when you choose the `preg_match` function (or use `preg_match_all` for your tests).

Comment: `\s+` and `\s*` is also not working - mh, ok it looks like it is not working on live regex but on regex101.com, strange

Comment: Your regex does not match 24hr time, only 12hr. `13:30 PM` does not exist, it must be `1:30 PM`. Have a look at http://ideone.com/JB4YLu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the regex you posted seems like you want to get the time from a multi-line string.

OK, the regex "\s" matches any new line, but in the case of your string there could be any number of white spaces.

Solution:

Replace \s with \s*

`/((?:(?:(?:[0][1-9]|1[0-2]|[0-9]):[0-5][0-9])\s(?:AM|PM)))/msiU`

`/((?:(?:(?:[0][1-9]|1[0-2]|[0-9]):[0-5][0-9])\s*(?:AM|PM)))/msiU`

\s* allows you to match any number of white space characters.

You can debug your regex at https://regex101.com/r/9Sz2Oi/1

Your corrected script at http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/joC (* Use preg_match_all)